# PHP compare strings error

Tags: php, string, compare

I am a beginner in PHP and I am trying to separate the input based on the argument. Following is my code but it seems that my `$arg` variables is never set. Can someone point out my error?

```
    $sender = $_GET['sender'];
    $receiver = $_GET['receiver'];
    $message = $_GET['message'];
    $temp = explode( '.', $message);
    $tempcnt = count($temp);
    echo $temp[$tempcnt - 1];
    if($tempcnt > 2)
    {
        if($temp[$tempcnt-1] === 'mp4')
            {$arg = 3;}
        elseif($temp[$tempcnt-1]==='jpg')
            {$arg = 2;}
        else
            {$arg = 1;}
    }
    echo "Value of arg is" . $arg;
```

I have even tried with `==` and `===` and `strcmp` in `if` but still same issue.

Comment: What's the value of `$message`?

Comment: Your code should work as long as `$message` has at least 2 `.` characters in it. If not, `if($tempcnt > 2)` will fail and it won't do any of the comparisons. So it will work for `foo.bar.jpg` but not `foo.jpg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was caused since i didn't realize i had compared for args > 2. Made it >=2 and viola it done!!
Thanks to @barmar for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
<?php
$temp strrchr("foo.jpg",".");
if($temp==".mp4")
$arg = 3;
elseif($temp==".jpg")
$arg = 2;
else $arg = 1;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

See also the other answers, but one possibility that hasn't been mentioned is that `==` and `===` and `strcmp` all compare case sensitively. So they won't find extensions like `.MP4`.

The solution in that case would be to use `strcasecmp`.

However, the first thing to do with problems like this is to output some more diagnostics, so that you can see for yourself what goes wrong. In this example, `echo $tempcnt;` after its assignment, or `else echo "did nothing"` after the outer `if {..}` block.
That way you'll be able to follow what the program flow is.